# Is there a way to get unbanned from Google AdSense?

Tags: google, google-adsense

As a young kid(15 years old) I used to open blogs on blogger and put Adsense ads on it. Because I was young and stupid I used to click on my own ads and did a lot of stupid things along that I don't even remember(it was 7 years ago...) so I got my self banned. After that I asked for friends to open for me accounts and of course they got banned too.

The problem I have is that it happened long time ago and I don't remember much, Not the sites I used to put the ads on or what exactly I did that got me banned, So when I tried to apply an appeal a year ago I got rejected.

Is there any chance for me to get unbanned? Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You wouldn't of been accepted at the age of 15 unless you lied about your age. Clicking on purpose isn't naughty, its actually fraud, and Google will treat that very seriously, its doubtful that your ever get that ban lifted.

Comment: So in your opinion I don't deserve a second chance? you don't think its a little harsh? we all lied a about our age on the internet at one point ... i had a blog on blogger with a lot of organic traffic from social medias and google search. just got a little bit greedy because i was young and stupid.

Comment: Unbanning you will be at there discretion. They only have methods to appeal a decision if they have made a mistake, in this case they haven't, so it makes no difference if you agree, or disagree with their actions, its not in your hands, its not your business.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a legal entity (such as a corporation or LLC) and open an account on its behalf. The contact person can be someone other than yourself, but you will still own the revenues as the owner of the legal entity. If you make lots of money then taking this route may actually have some financial benefits. You should consult though an accountant in order to understand the full tax implications in your jurisdiction.

Comment: My brother just asked me if i got banned does that mean that he cant use it either? because we have the same ip and the same home address.

Comment: The ban in your case is probably on you as a person and not your ip address (assuming you haven't been doing other hackery stuff). But don't be tempted to use a fake name, you might have trouble cashing the revenue.

Comment: when i got banned i tried to open new accounts and they too got banned(with the same info as the blocked one). im not talking about fake id im talking about my brother(not fake brother) wanting to open a youtube channel and monetize it.

Comment: I don't think he should have trouble, let him just try on fresh browser (i.e., after clearing cookies etc.). Note that if your home internet connection is regular (e.g. DSL) then your ip address is dynamic, and likely to have changed over time.

Comment: @RonKantor "i tried to open new accounts..." - did you do the same "stupid" things with the new accounts? How quickly were the new accounts banned? (Just curious.) Whilst most home internet connections have dynamic IPs, some are static and some (whilst still classed as "dynamic") will keep the same IP for very long periods of time (years). But even if IP addresses change, they will presumably still resolve to the same ISP.

Comment: @w3d With the new account i didn't click on my own ads i just shared posts on Facebook. I actually just yesterday discovered that the account is disabled.

Comment: @w3d Google is pretty good at associating accounts with even with dynamic IP's, due to the fact they now share information across services. Logging into one account and then another would flag the other account if the same IP was used at the time, or if a new IP address was used then they could obtain this information through the cookie ID's that they store.

Comment: They could also associate the C Class IP addresses, most ISPS use specific c class IP addresses for an area, not hard for Google to identify people based on that and browsing habits, since that leaves a unique footprint. It wouldn't surprise me if they already do this, because its identification = $$$. A lot of companies can associate anonymous data and actually identify people, confirmed by various documentarys  and by Snowden too.

Comment: @RonKantor they would of banned your 2nd account because your banned. You made one mistake and then another one, my advice is that you read the terms and conditions before using such services. In this instance your best of learning from it and moving on, there are other ad services that you can use that doesn't involve Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can [appeal AdSense ban for invalid activity by filling out this form](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2707037).

Answer (score 2):

Google is pretty cut and dried about this sort of activity. I would highly doubt that you'd be able to ever open an account with them, nor even appeal successfully. Unfortunate for you, but they do spell it out in their terms & conditions.

You can certainly try to hide your association with a company which conducts advertising on your behalf, but they aren't stupid and they will check ownership and associations so it would have to be clever. I guess you don't have anything to lose.

Your brother is a separate entity but frankly, if I were him, to be safe I'd either use a different network, a smartphone, or a VPN service and ensure that I was registering on a different IP address. Google is under no obligation to give anyone an account if they choose not too, and they may assign guilt by association, so it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Google has the right to terminate anyone's account for any reason, this includes good standing family members. Several companies, have and do regularly ban family members even, if they do not break the rules, but this is normally associated with households, rather than multiple addresses and surnames. Google is likely to run various checks before making payment, it wouldn't be hard to identify peoples previous addresses and relate. Amazon UK, for example is known for banning entire households rather than just the individual. My advice, learn from it, move on and use a different ad service.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a second chance, and google will leave you banned.

That same situation happened to me, and recently I was asking on **[this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87180/is-it-possible-to-use-one-adsense-account-with-other-youtube-account)** question on web aplications because there's no way if you done that kind of activity that you'll get unbanned.

So, the only solution is to open another account and associate it with anything you like.